# Парсинг видео с ВКонтакте

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ, видео, вконтакте

Может кто то сталкивался, когда получаешь страницу с видео допустим
http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-66270740&id=167568548&hash=2a3a79fd5ead4c2e
то в коде стоит верный video_vtag, а когда с помощью Сurl, то там не правильный. Пробовал ставить заголовки, как на странице и нефига (

Comment: Куки не забыли в curl поставить из браузера — в них авторизация.

Comment: ну так дело в том что эта ссылка доступна и без авторизации. и в браузере никакие куки не создаются для этой страницы

Answer (score 1):

```
curl 'http://cs507407.vk.me/u112847320/video/l_ff5a5b75.jpg' -H 'Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Host: cs507407.vk.me' -H 'If-Modified-Since: Wed, 24 Apr 2013 15:54:42 GMT' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0'
```

Работает на ура.

На всякий случай поясню: -H -- это хидер. Выстави такие же в твоём запросе и будет работать

Comment: C фото как раз проблем никаких, проблема именно с видео. И состоит в том что приходит страница с неправильным video_vtag

Comment: всё правильно показывает, такой-же как и в браузере.

    $ curl --silent 'http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=-66270740&id=167568548&hash=2a3a79fd5ead4c2e'  |grep video_vtag
    var video_vtag = 'd7b9766e40';